# Cannot specify link libraries for target "pluginlib_utest"

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm building ROS on Yosemite and have built 72/196 packages successfully after a bit of debugging. Now I am stumped at this error:

```
-- catkin 0.5.89
-- Boost version: 1.56.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
CMake Warning at /Users/kal04p/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:29 (message):
  skipping gtest 'pluginlib_utest' in project 'pluginlib'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:35 (catkin_add_gtest)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:36 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "pluginlib_utest" which is not
  built by this project.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/kal04p/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pluginlib/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
<== Failed to process package 'pluginlib':
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199640/cannot-specify-link-libraries-for-target-%22pluginlib_utest%22/) by [chris_](https://answers.ros.org/users/20918/chris_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2014-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was fixed by `brew install gtest`. Hopefully useful for future visitors.

---

Originally posted by [chris_](https://answers.ros.org/users/20918/chris_/) with karma: 83 on 2014-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0